# What is the name for a track hidden before the CD content?

Tags: terminology, hidden-track, cd

If I rewind the track 1 of the debut album by The Music, I can get to track 0. To play this hidden track I need to rewind until I reach its beginning; I found no other way to access it.

Is there a name for such hidden tracks?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a more specific term than "hidden track", but I wasn't aware that what you describe is possible so I am prepared to be corrected :P.

Comment: Does the CD player actually say 'track 0'?

Comment: @DA. My current CD player is unable to access such tracks and I don't have the old one anymore. However, as far as I remember, the display showed track 1 with negative time value (example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTbPsAdg1VA).

Comment: I have seen a pregap track set at track 1 but timed at 2.20 so you would have to rewind, so you are still on track 1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are looking for a technical term it is ["pregap"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pregap). The article states:

> Not all CD drives can properly extract such hidden tracks. Some drives will report errors when reading these tracks, and some will seem to extract them properly, but the extracted file will contain only silence.

There is also a [list of albums with tracks hidden in the pregap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_albums_with_tracks_hidden_in_the_pregap) in Wikipedia.

I don't know any hardware or software player that can access it directly for sure but I would give [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) a try.

Comment: I can recommend the 2manydjs pregap track on there mix album 'as heard on soulwax radio pt2'